# iOS CallKit mute button auto deselect after few seconds

Tags: ios, callkit

On iOS, when app is in background or killed state, and receive and pickup the incoming VoIP call, then on native iOS callkit dialer(UI) the mute button is automatically selected or deselected. Please see this video for the behavior:

https://www.loom.com/share/4e32e356be1540f4b64b66da294e78f0

There are no code written for mute/unmute part on my `CXProviderDelegate` in my app. So not sure what could be the reason of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's getting deselected is the operations are not listened in the app.

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetMutedCallAction) {
    sharedInstance.isMuted = action.isMuted
// This line is very important in this
    action.fulfill()
// **** //
}
```